# How to pass whole query string into one single variable through ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a website where I have to save search when I press the save search I have the whole query string like this `?s=&variable1=&variable2=` ... and over 100 other variables I want to take this whole query string and save into a single variable to save it inside database column url

```
var query=form.serialize
```

how to save whole query string into a single variable to pass it through ajax to php?

The url is relative sometimes fields are about properties sometimes about cars sometimes about mobile phones so can't call every single one.

Comment: this variable so is from a form?

Answer (score 0):

You can save save URL parameters using like this:

```
let query = window.location.search;
```

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: ok how to do i pass the whole query through ajax to php i mean $query=$_POST['??']

Comment: i want the user to retrieve his/her searches in the future

Comment: You can use ajax to pass that data using POST method (examples you can find right here https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ ). Than you have to handle this post in PHP were you can collect that data from that ajax call using $_POST array and there you can save it to the database for example.

Comment: @RamySafi If you're sending a POST request, use `xhr.send(query)` to send the query string as POST data.